# How to filter out IP addresses from Google Analytics into Big Query

Tags: sql, filter, google-analytics, google-bigquery, ip

I realize that we are not able to filter ip addresses from Big Query, only Google Analytics but I have heard that I can create a custom dimension in GA with those IPs and use that custom dimension to filter them out in big query. Is this true or is there another way to do it without having to change the view that Big Query is pointing at?

Here is an example code for our users:

```
##standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT fullVisitorId
  FROM `olympicchannel-ga.168112989.ga_sessions*`
  WHERE 1=1
    AND [cast(parse_date('%Y%m%d', date) as date)=daterange]
    AND NOT [bot_traffic]
    AND trafficsource.source NOT IN ('platform.utest.com')

  UNION ALL

  SELECT fullVisitorId
  FROM `olympicchannel-ga.178594195.ga_sessions*`
  WHERE 1=1
    AND [cast(parse_date('%Y%m%d', date) as date)=daterange]
    AND NOT [bot_traffic]
    AND trafficsource.source NOT IN ('platform.utest.com')
)
```

The first is our website users and the second is for our app, two different views.

Comment: You're not allowed to keep IP addresses in GA regardless of the method you're using to get it into GA. Since the ToS states that PII is not allowed. I would suggest you add the filter to the view you're pulling the data from instead.

Answer (score 1):

You´re not allowed to save IP as GA custom Dimension
Even if you were technically able to do so I would rather use the exclude IP functionality within GA admin Section. see
[image]
If you´re in Europe you may have to send anonymised ip to GA, see [IP Anonymization in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en)

in this case you probably want to create a variable in the dataLayer with the information Internal or External IP, push that to GA as a custom dimension with scope session and then exclude that afterwards in BQ.

Another option would be to handle that directly in the Pixel container (e.g. Google Tag Manager...)